# Why do i get "program received signal: "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" on NSString veriable

Tags: objective-c, if-statement, exc-bad-access

I just recently started learning Objective C, when i run the next program i get error
"program received signal: "EXC_BAD_ACCESS"
For the code line

```
 if([*userChoice isEqualToString:@"yes"])
```

The full code is:

```
void initGame (void);
void restartGame(void);
void toGoOn(char *playerChoice);


int guess=-1;
int from=-1;
int to=-1;
bool playStatus=true;
bool gameStatus=true;
int answer=-1;
NSString *userChoice[10];

//if true the game is on

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {

        GuessManager *game=GUESS;  
        NSLog(@"Hello, lets play");
        NSLog(@"Please provide a positive range in which you would like to play");
      do{
          initGame();
          [game setnumberToGuess:from :to];
        do {                       
            printf("Make you guess:");
            scanf("%d", &guess);
            [game setUserGuess:guess];
            [game checkUserGuess];
            if([game getDidIgetIt])
            {
                playStatus=false;               
            } 
            else
            {
                playStatus=true;
            }

        } while (playStatus);
         restartGame();
      }while(gameStatus);  
        printf("Thanks For Playing PanGogi Games! GoodBye");
    }
    return 0;
}





void initGame (void)
{
    printf("from:");
    scanf("%d",&from);
    printf("to:");
    scanf("%d",&to);    
}

void restartGame(void)
{
    printf("Would you like to continue?(yes/no)");
    scanf("%s",&userChoice); 
    //scanf("%d",&answer); 

   // if(answer==1)
    if([*userChoice isEqualToString:@"yes"])
    {
        gameStatus=true;
    }
    else
    {
        gameStatus=false;
    }
}
```

I understand that its related to the NSString variable userChoice and how its used in
the if, but what i cant find is what am i doing wrong.

Please help :)

Comment: if([userChoice isEqualToString:@"yes"])

Comment: You're using `NSString` as if it was `char`.

Comment: try userChoice instead of *userChoice

Comment: Simply removing the `*` won't be enough. The usage of `scanf` with an `NSString` is wrong too. And why are you declaring a C-array of `NSStrings`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 3 errors in the code

1) I think you are getting confused with NSString and C style char array... You just need to use single NSString object to save multi character data..

```
NSString *userChoice;
```

2) Since you want to input data using scanf, you need a C style character array. scanf won't work with NSString types.

```
char tempArray[10];
int count = scanf("%s",&tempArray);
userChoice  = [NSString stringWithBytes:tempArray length:count encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

3) Now you can use NSString directly.. No need for pointer like syntax

```
if( [userChoice isEqualToString: @"yes"]){
   .....
   .....
}
```

Comment: Cant i compare just two chars. I mean to leave userChoise as char and in scanf to receive just one character (y/n) and to compare it to a char y or n.  how do i compare just two chars properly?

Comment: you can just use a C char variable , input using `scanf` and `%c`.. and compare just like you do in C, ie `if(c == 'y'){..}`

Comment: OK, i changed the dikleration to 
char *userChoice;
 and the compering to:
    if(userChoice=="y")
and when i run it it doesn't get that y equals to y.
and on the compering i get notification "string literal is unspecified"

Answer (score 0):

You're using `NSString` as if it was `char`. It's not. It's a class that represents a string.

The `scanf` function is a C function and needs a char array, not an `NSString`.

```
char str[80];
scanf("%s", &str);
```

You can initialize an `NSString` object with a `char` array like this:

```
NSString *userChoice = [NSString stringWithCString:str encoding:NSASCIIEncoding];
```

And compare like this:

```
if ([userChoice isEqualToString:@"yes"]) {
   ...
} else {
   ...
}
```